# UIButton as switch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a push-on-push-off-like button with custom images in Xcode4 for iOS.
The code I'm using is

```
- (IBAction)btnAll:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

That works fine for now.
But my problem is, that when I'm toggling on, I press it on, then it is popping off again and then finally on.
The app works, but that is really ugly, though.

I firstly set the "highlighted" image to on. So when I highlight the button, it is on and that popping to on. That works fine. But when I turn it off again, the problem is the same, in the reverse direction.

I tried to put that code:

```
- (IBAction)btnAll:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(button.selected)
    {
        [button setImage[UIImage imageNamed@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage[UIImage imageNamed@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

But as long `button.selected = !button.selected` there is no difference.
So it won't make any change.

I also tried to trigger the IBAction on »Touch Down« but you can imagine how frustrating this will look like.

Has anybody got a solution for that problem?
Did anybody struggle with that one too?

Greets, thanks a lot
Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem to this before, the button works a little strangely when tapping.  Try this code and let me know if it works

```
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(button.selected)
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    button.selected = !button.selected;

    If (button.selected) {
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

When you tap and hold on a button the state is actually Highlighted & Selected so you need an image for both Highlight and selected state.

Answer (score 3):

Don't manually switch the images around, just set the selected state's image in Interface Builder and swap the `selected` property over when the button is tapped.

Comment: It is also worth stopping the button adjusting its image when highlighted as this is not wanted in this situation.

Comment: As you can read in my post, I just tried this as a solution for my original problem. So the main problem remains. I just recognized, that when I tap the button very short, the highlighted image disappears, the original off state image shows up again and then it pop to "selected" state. It seams to be too slow...

Comment: [Sample Video.](https://files.me.com/julianweinert/xpa7rt) It looks the same on the original iPhone Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jim, your code needs little modification as below...

```
[button setImage[UIImage imageNamed@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage[UIImage imageNamed@"on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: doesn't look you're agreeing with @jim. you don't need to swap images.

Comment: @XJones:Thanks, my mistake! I have change the sample code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have two buttons created.

place buttons one above one.

Can set Default & Selected images using Custom Button option in design builder.

```
-(void)firstButtonClicked {

firstButton.hidden = YES;
secondButton.hidden = NO;

}

-(void)secondButtonClicked {

firstButton.hidden = NO;
secondButton.hidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jim - when do u switch the isSelected state? isHighlighted gets called twice for every press. My hacked version of UIButton switch below : -

```
class ButtonSwitch: UIButton {

  override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
    if allControlEvents == .touchUpInside {
      isSelected.toggle()
    }
    super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
  }
}
```